# Javascript error function is logging the error message as 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I'm attempting to run my Parse cloud code job, however it's running into an error. When it hits this error, it runs `function(error)` and prints out `Got an error undefined : undefined`.

Because the `error` valuable is undefined, I'm having a hard time figuring out which one of the functions it's running is causing the problem, as well as where in that function it's failing. Is there anything I can log in `status.error` to see what's going wrong?

```
Parse.Cloud.job("MCBackground", function(request, status) {
    // ... other code to setup usersQuery ...
    Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

    var usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);

    return usersQuery.each(function(user) {
            return processUser(user)
                .then(function(eBayResults) {
                    return mcComparison(user, eBayResults);
                });
        })
        .then(function() {
            // Set the job's success status
            status.success("MatchCenterBackground completed successfully.");
        }, function(error) {
            // Set the job's error status
            status.error("Got an error " + error + " : " + error.message);
        });
});
```

Comment: Curiously, if error is undefined, then error.message should trigger an exception like "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'message' of undefined"

Comment: My thoughts exactly. Very strange stuff.

Answer (score 3):

What has worked well for my clients that are experiencing this error is to simply convert the error object into JSON then work with that error as a string e.g. by logging the error to the console.

```
    Parse.Cloud.job("MCBackground", function(request, status) {     
// ... other code to setup usersQuery ...     
Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();      
var usersQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);      
return usersQuery.each(function(user) {             
return processUser(user)                 
.then(function(eBayResults) {                     
return mcComparison(user, eBayResults);                 
});         
})         
.then(function() {             
// Set the job's success status             
status.success("MatchCenterBackground completed successfully.");         
}, function(error) {             
// Set the job's error status             
status.error("Got an error " + JSON.stringify(error));         
}); 
});
```